# Calcular el promedio de los numeros de un array

Tags: javascript

esto tratando de calcular el promedio de varios números que hay dentro de un array

PROBLEMA: La luna de Endor pierde temperatura día a día,
para ello hay que hacer un monitoreo constante, Cree una
función de flecha que permita calcular la temperatura media de
la luna a partir de la temperatura máxima y mínima de cada día.

Este es el codigo, pero me sale Nan

```
let promedio = (temperaturas) => {

    let tempMaxima = Math.max(temperaturas);
    let tempMinima = Math.min(temperaturas);


    let promedio = (tempMaxima + tempMinima) / 2;

   
    console.log("La tempertura promedio fu de: " + promedio);

}

promedio(temperaturas = [17, 35, 26, 65]);
```

Comment: Ejecútalo así : `promedio([17,35,26,65])`

Comment: Me sigue saliendo NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.max()` y `Math.min()` no reciben arreglos. Esperan una lista de parámetros numéricos o de cadenas de texto conformadas solo por números. Es por eso que estás obteniendo `NaN`.

Una forma de resolverlo es con el operador spread `...`:

```
let tempMaxima = Math.max(...temperaturas);
let tempMinima = Math.min(...temperaturas);
```

Otras opciones son mediante `Math.max.apply()` y `Math.min.apply()` pasándole `null` o `Math` como primer parámetro:

```
let tempMaxima = Math.max.apply(null, temperaturas);
let tempMinima = Math.min.apply(null, temperaturas);
```

O mediante la función de los arreglos `reduce`:

```
function arrayMin(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (p, v) {
    return ( p < v ? p : v );
  });
}

function arrayMax(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (p, v) {
    return ( p > v ? p : v );
  });
}
```

Soluciones posibles obtenidas de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript) de Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Usa el [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (...) para convertir el arreglo en una secuencia de parámetros para las funciones `min` y `max`

```js
let promedio = (temperaturas) => {

let tempMaxima = Math.max(...temperaturas);
let tempMinima = Math.min(...temperaturas);


let promedio = (tempMaxima + tempMinima) / 2;

 console.log("La tempertura promedio fu de: " + promedio);
}

promedio([17, 35, 26, 65])
```